# Repo-wide configuration of git

Tags: git

How can i make a persistent git-config file for the whole repository?

I know, that there is a system wide, a user and a repository configuration. What i want is a configuration wich is automatically downloaded with the repository. Something, which acts like `.gitignore`. `.git/config` is not an options, since it is locally created.

I'll give you an example:

```
[branch "master"]
    mergeoptions = --no-ff
```

With this setting, i achieve that every merge to the master branch is a no-ff merge. This is useful, especially for users which either don't know, or forget to use this option whenever they merge into the master branch. If i store it in `.git/config` it only stays on my computer.

There are more use cases. I could add something like:

```
[vim]                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    settings = tabstop=3 expandtab softtabstop=3 shiftwidth=3
```

and in my .vimrc (at the end)

```
let git_settings = system("git config --get vim.settings")
if strlen(git_settings)
   exe "set" git_settings
endif
```

With this every one using vim has the right tabbing-format, which is especially crucial for python projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i asked around and there is no such possibility. Actually this behavior is dangerous as remote code execution can be used.